# What does it mean for two terms to be equal?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I was learning a bit of model theory on my own and I faced a problem in understanding what an atomic formula is. I understood the meaning of term, which is

$(1)$- Every constant symbol and variable symbol is a term.

$(2)$- Let $f$ be any $n$- arity function symbol. And let $t_1,t_2....t_n$ be terms then,
$f(t_1,t_2...,t_n)$ is also a term.

Let me know if there any mistakes in understanding of term

And using this we define atomic formula as,

(1) If $t_1,t_2$ are terms then,
$t_1=t_2$ is atomic formula.

(2) If $t_1,t_2,....,t_n$ are terms and $R$ be any $n$ -arity relation symbol. Then $R(t_1,t_2...,t_n)$ is atomic formula.

Now I don't understand the condition $(1)$. What does '$=$' mean there?

Does it mean the general equal to sign we refer to or is it something else

Comment: The "$=$" must be looked at as a logical symbol (so part of underlying language). Atomic formula "$t_1=t_2$" does *not* state that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the same strings of symbols. The formula can be true in a structure for some assignment and be false for some other assignment.

Comment: Example: "$x=y$" where $x$ and $y$ denote distinct variables. In the common structure for natural numbers this formula is satisfied by an assignment $s$ with $s(x)=4=s(y)$ but not satisfied by assignment $s'$ with $s'(x)=7$ and $s'(y)=12$.

Comment: Note that it really only makes sense to ask whether $t=s$ holds, for terms $t,s$, in the presence of a **structure** and, if appropriate, a **variable assignment** of elements of that structure to any free variables in $t$ or $s$. So for example "$x*y=y*x$" is true in every abelian group according to every variable assignment but is only true in (say) the nonabelian group $S_{17}$ according to *some* variable assignments (some pairs of elements of $S_{17}$ commute, others don't). So at the syntax level, "$t=s$" makes sense but isn't "ready to evaluate" yet, if that helps.

Comment: Two names for the same object.

Answer (score 1):

No, here, it does not mean equality or terms (which would mean they are literally the same strings of characters). Rather, is a symbol which is interpres as equality, much the same as the symbol $+$ in the term "$x+y$" does not mean that we add terms (addition makes no sense for terms), it's just a symbol that is (typically) interpreted as addition.

For example, if $M$ is a structure and $t_1, t_2$ are terms without variables, then $(t_1+t_2)^M=t_1^M +^Mt_2^M$ and $M\models t_1=t_2$ when $t_1^M =t_2^M$. Both these things depend on the interpretation of $+$ – as well as other constant and function symbols occuring in $t_1,t_2$ – in $M$.

Comment: So according to you, it depends on interpretation of $=$ in the structure?

Comment: @Rahul Imagine trying to define what an "equation" is.... that's what clause (1) is doing.

Comment: @Ned, So are we talking about the equality between terms in sense of structure?

Comment: Interpreting a formula (i.e. deciding whether it is satisfied or not) requires a structure (i.e. a domain for the variables and interpretations of the function and predicate symbols) and an assignment of values to the free variables of the formula. But NONE of that is in the definitions you wrote above, which are simply defining (precisely) what the formulas of the language are, without saying ANYTHING about what they are supposed to mean.

Comment: @Rahul: In my answer, I'm assuming you're working in first order logic with equality (which is what you usually do in model theory), in this case the answer is no (there is only one interpretation of $=$ in the structure, which is the true equality. If you work in FOL without equality (so in particular, you allow different interpretations of equality), then yes, it does. In any case, whether a formula is true in a given structure depends on the interpretation of *constant* and *function* symbols, because they determine the interpretations of *terms*. In the formula itself, $=$ is just a symbol